# Importing SlidingMenu in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, slidingmenu

I am getting started with `SlidingMenu` for Android. [As instructed](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), I have imported the latest `ActionBarSherlock` into my workspace; it went well. I have also downloaded the `SlidingMenu` as a zip file and extracted it in a folder.

I tried importing it as an Android library project however, Eclipse just imports the `examples` folder and not the library. The examples thus imported are full of error markers.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First extract .zip file and then after import separately two project 
Example and Library

then folow this points

1. remove supportv4.jar from lib folder of library
2. remove supportv4.jar from lib folder of ExampleListActivity project
3. import ABS (ACtion bar sherlock Library )
4. then apply this ABS Library project as library to your sliding menu library
5. modify SlidingFragmentActivity class from sliding menu library . currently this class extended from FragmentActivity change to SherlockFragmentActivity.

And i successfully imported this project and posting answer.
look here [image: Check here]